# Javascript: toString function for custom exception not displaying expected output

Tags: javascript, exception, javascript-objects

This page outlines how to create custom exceptions in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw.

However, the custom exception isn't printing the expected output. The desired output only occurs when invoking `console.log(e.toString())` but the goal is to see the desired output with `console.log(e)`.

Desired output with `console.log(e)`:

```
500: Unexpected error
```

Actual output with `console.log(e)`:

```
{
  statusCode: 500,
  statusMessage: "Unexpected error",
  toString: function () {
        return this.statusCode + ': ' + this.statusMessage;
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
function TestException(statusCode, statusMessage) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.statusCode + ': ' + this.statusMessage;
    };
}

try {
    throw new TestException(500, 'Unexpected error');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have an exception that help you:

```
const TestException = (statusCode, statusMessage) => {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    this.toString = () => {
        return this.statusCode + ': ' + this.statusMessage;
    }

    if(!isNaN(this.statusCode) || this.statusMessage !== null) {
        throw this.toString();
    }
}

try {
    throw TestException("500", 'Unexpected error');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't update the `statusCode` and `statusMessage` properties?

Comment: yeah , sorry   , but if you insert an exception you must resolve the problem